# Neo4j error because of new Java version

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, neo4j

I am trying to run my rails api which uses neo4j. Everything was previously working fine but I am now getting this error:

`Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 7 or OpenJDK(TM) to run Neo4j Server.`

This is what I get when I `java -version`

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Can someone guide me as to how I can downgrade from Java 8 to Java 7. Nothing seems to work.

**EDIT**: that was fixed and now I am getting this new error any ideas

```
`raise_error': Could not create token (Neo4j::Server::CypherResponse::ResponseError)
```

Comment: Point your java_home environmental variable to a JDK 7 installation instead of the JDK 8 installation.

Comment: Yes I got that up and running, now I am, getting this error any ideas on this :
`raise_error': Could not create token (Neo4j::Server::CypherResponse::ResponseError)

Comment: I am unfortunately not an expert on Neo4j. Would probably be better to start a new question on that specific issue :)